# Create installation file for any PHP project

Tags: php, git, laravel

The title can be a little bit misleading but this is what I need to achieve.
I have a project which resides in Github. I need to install these files in multiple domains.

So just like wordpress I need to have a simple PHP installation page where I take all the necessary details like site name, DB username , DB name etc and when I click install button it is going to do the following.

```
> git clone the project files
> create new directory
> Run composer install (Assume the project is Laravel 4 App)
> Checking the provided DB user and pass if they are correct, if yes migrating the DB, if No redirect back with an error.
> Display the 'installation success' page if everything is OK.
```

I am aware that some activities may require admin privilege and I have it. The web server behind all domains is Apache. I have never done this kind of thing before and so I have no Idea where to get started. Any link or detailed explanations will be fine for now.

Comment: https://www.docker.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the project [Laravel Web Installer](https://github.com/RachidLaasri/LaravelInstaller) its a step towards what you want, it will allow a user to do all the configuration from a web interface.

It also can also handle checking for server requirements, checking folder permissions, migrate the database and seed tables.